# Timeline with transparent markers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to create a timeline (or more specifically in my case, a scroll indicator) with dynamically placed transparent markers that would allow you to see a background-image behind it, but also hides/masks the timeline it is on.
Let me show you a screenshot of what im trying to achieve for clarification:[timeline with transparent markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFkPX.png)

So i have a timeline which is gradually filled in as a user scrolls through the page and i want to dynamically add markers to the timeline to indicate "points of interest". So far this should be relatively easy, but... these markers should obscure/mask/clip the timeline itself (so you don't see the line behind the marker) and be transparent at the same time so you qould be able to see an image that is behind it, for example.

Is this possible with a combination of html, css, js/jquery and/or svg?

I've seen loads of examples where the markers have a solid background-color which is the same as the background-color of it's parent element to create the illusion it is transparent, but i've never seen it with a truly transparent markers.

I would greatly appreciate some insight from you guys, because i'm currently stumped.

Some code of what i have so far, just in case:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/HighlyEffective/pen/dWOXbG)

js:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

        var $progressContElement = $("<div id='progress-cont' class='scroll-indicator-wrap'><div id='progress-bar__timeline' class='progress-bar__timeline'></div></div>");

        // Create the progress bar itself
        var $progressBarElement = $("<div id='progress-bar' class='scroll-indicator progress-bar__timeline'></div>");
        $progressBarElement.css("height", "0%");

        $progressContElement.append($progressBarElement);

        var $locationObject = $("#wrapper-main");
        $locationObject.prepend($progressContElement);

        var poi = $(".scroll-indicator__POI");
        var poiLength = $(".scroll-indicator__POI").length;
        var pracPoiLength = poiLength - 1;
        console.log(poiLength);
        $(poi).each(function(i) {
            console.log(i);
            $progressContElement.append("<div class='progress-bar__timeline-marker'></div>");
            var markerOffset = parseInt((i / pracPoiLength) * 100);
            $(".progress-bar__timeline-marker:eq("+i+")").addClass("test").css("top", markerOffset+"%");
        });

        // Event handler that updates the width of the progress bar based
        // on how far the contentToTrack elemt has been scrolled
        $(window).scroll(function(e){
            var pageHeight = $(window).height();
            var $container = $("#wrapper-main");

            // Adjusted height
            var adjustedHeight = $container.innerHeight() - pageHeight;
            var progress = (($(window).scrollTop() / adjustedHeight) * 100);
            $progressBarElement.css("height", progress + "%");
        });

});
```

css:

```
 .scroll-indicator__POI {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #e7ffdf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.scroll-indicator-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
}

.progress-bar__timeline {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #000;
}

#progress-bar__timeline {
    height: 100%;
}

.scroll-indicator {
    background-color: red;
}

.progress-bar__timeline-marker {
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper-main">
    <div class="scroll-indicator__POI" style="background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any')"></div>
    <div class="scroll-indicator__POI" style="background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/750/480/any')"></div>
    <div class="scroll-indicator__POI" style="background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/640/500/any')"></div>
   <div class="scroll-indicator__POI"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are too many ways to build something like this. What you need to do is pick one and try it.

Comment: Could you name/explain one for me?

Comment: Plain HTML and CSS is sufficient. Try making this yourself and then come here for help when you have written some code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't achieve this with plain HTML and CSS. 
I already have some code for the scroll-indicator and timeline, it's just the transparent markers that are the issue. If you could point me in the right direction for this, i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: You keep saying you "have some code" but I don't see any. SO is for fixing 
and understanding problems, not getting free full solutions. You can't expect others to do work while you're skipping out on doing any.

Comment: I only said that i have code once, dude. I don't need someone to talk down to me, i just want some help. I know what SO is for, i don't need a full solution, i just want some ideas to help me with this tricky concept. 
Here is what i have so far, although i dont see how this will help with the general concept: https://codepen.io/HighlyEffective/pen/dWOXbG

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible.

1. What you want to do is to swap out the `.progress-bar__timeline-marker` for a filled/active image, once the user has scrolled past the marker. This can be done in JS.
2. In order to have fully transparent markers that hides the red line, you will need to use [CSS masks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask). You want two images: the first image will be a circular mask that **hides** the red line that goes through the marker, and the second image will be the actual, active marker.

z-indexes: line < circular mask that hides line < transparent marker

This is not possible with pure HTML/CSS.